# How do I run dbt macro multiple times based on a variable from a select statement?

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbt

I have a problem with automatically granting rights to multiple roles per different dbt models.

I have a snowflake table with Model_Name and a role_name(s) column. One to many.
I need to post_hook macro

> {{ grant_select_on_schemas( "ROLE_NAME" ) }}

; as many times as a role_name appears in the table for a selected Model_Name, with "ROLE_NAME" being dynamically assigned based on the values on the snowflake table.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated as I'm very fresh to jinja.

BIG thanks

Comment: How does your macro look like?

Comment: Use a Jinja for loop, pass in the required values via the for loop and call the macro with the variable as an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way is to set the permissions in the configuration for your project and/or models.

In `dbt_project.yml`:

```
models:
  my_project:
    +grants:
      select:
        - role1
        - role2
```

This will set the grant on all models in your project. You can go down into directory level, if needed.

If you want to set grants at the model level:

```
{{
    config({
        "materialized": 'table',
        "grants": {
            '+select': ['role1', 'role2],
        },
    })
}}
```

If you specify grants in both `dbt_project.yml` and in the model, the grants will stack.

Older method (not recommended):
Create a macro:

```
{% macro grant_select_on_schemas(database_schemas) %}
  {% for (database, schema) in database_schemas %}
    grant usage on database {{ database }} to role role1;
    grant usage on database {{ database }} to role role2;

    grant usage on schema {{ database }}.{{ schema }} to role role1;
    grant usage on schema {{ database }}.{{ schema }} to role role2;

    grant select on all tables in database {{ database }} to role role1;
    grant select on all tables in database {{ database }} to role role2;
  {% endfor %}
{% endmacro %}
```

And call as a post-hook in `dbt_project.yml`

```
on-run-end:
  - "{{ grant_select_on_schemas(database_schemas)}}"
```

More info:

- Configuring grants: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/grants
- `on-run-end` grant examples: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/project-configs/on-run-start-on-run-end
- `on-run-end` context: https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/dbt-jinja-functions/on-run-end-context

Comment: BIG Thanks, Adam! Haven't thought of that approach at all. Was overly focused on using macro all the way.  Will get through "more info" you've posted! Thanks again! That's a massive help! :)